# using PHContentEditingController without photo editing extension?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension

Can i use **PhotosUI framework's PHContentEditingController protocol** inside my app to edit any given image or asset without having to create a photo editing extension?
The question is does Apple let us access to this content editing capabilities within the app? so i can take any asset i want edit it and and retrieve the image for inside app use prepossess?

In [PHContentEditingController Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PhotosUI/Reference/PHContentEditingController_Protocol/index.html) it says the use of this protocol is in order to create an extension:

> **The PHContentEditingController protocol defines methods you implement in a custom view controller class in order to create a Photos extension**. The Photos app hosts your extension’s view controller to provide a user interface for editing photo or video assets.

Any ideas how can i use this methods for inApp editing?